# Save a file path stored in a userform textbox to a folder

Tags: excel, vba

I have a folder named "Images" and a user is prompted to upload an image in a userform that I created.
The uploading command works well.
The image filepath automatically uploads to a textbox.
How do I save the filepath from the textbox to an image in the folder I created folder?
I can't find a code for this.

Comment: "save the path to an image"? what exactly do you mean? Please make an attempt at the code yourself and include what you came up with in your question, because as it stands, your question is unclear.

Comment: How is this related to Excel? Please show your code.